# React - call function from props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to call function addPost from props through the tree of children but see "props.addPost is not a function" error  I suggested that it`s a lost of context and tried to use class component with bind but the same result.

state.js

```
...
export let addPost = (postMessage) =>{
    let newPost = {
       link: 'www.google.com',
       img: 'https://arthomework.ru/upload/iblock/b63/b63c8ab62c0250037748e471e2fac87f.jpg',
       alt: 'racoon',
       text: postMessage,
       count: '0',
       id: 4
    };

    state.profilePage.postItems.push(newPost);

    rerenderEntireTree(state);
}
export default state;
```

App.js

```
                <Route path="/profile" render={ ()=> <Profile 
                                                        state={props.state.profilePage}
                                                        addPost={props.addPost}

                                                      /> }
                                                      />
```

App`s child Profile.jsx

```
const Profile = (props) =>{
    return(
      <div>
            <MyPosts posts={props.state.postItems} addPost={props.addPost} />
      </div>

    )
}
```

next child

```
const MyPosts = (props) =>{
    let newPost = React.createRef();
    let addPost = (props) =>{ 
    let text = newPost.current.value;
       try{
        props.addPost(text);
        } catch(e){
        alert('Ошибка ' + e.name + ":" + e.message + "\n" + e.stack);
      }
    };

    return(
        <div className="posts">
          <div className={classes.title}>My posts</div>

          <form action="" className={classes.form}>
            <textarea 
              name="posts" 
              placeholder="your news..." 
              className={classes.textarea}
              ref={newPost}
              >
            </textarea>
            <button className={classes.button} value="Send" onClick={addPost}> </button> 
          </form>
```

Comment: You need to import addPost

Answer (score 0):

On your `addPost` method of the `MyPosts` component you expect the props as a parameter, which instead you get the event itself and obviously does't have the `addPost` function in it.

```
// no parameter needed here.
let addPost = () =>{ 
    let text = newPost.current.value;
       try{
        props.addPost(text);
        } catch(e){
        alert('Ошибка ' + e.name + ":" + e.message + "\n" + e.stack);
      }
    };
```

Comment: How I can fix it?